# What is the best board for setting up an SSH protocol to an Arduino?

Tags: arduino-uno, sketch, uploading, ssh

I currently have a project using an Arduino R3, set up across the room from my computer. This has become quite annoying, as every time I want to push something to the Arduino I have to get up and move either the computer or the Arduino to another location, plug it in, and hope my code works the first time, lest I have to repeat the test over and over again. I am trying to set up an SSH server between my Raspberry Pi 2 and computer so I can just push new sketches over SSH, however, I use my Pi 2 for other projects occasionally and want to purchase a second board specifically for this purpose. Is there a good, cheap, board with wifi built in (besides the Pi 3) that I could use for this? Any suggestions?

Comment: How is SSH helping achieve your goals?

Comment: https://hackaday.io/project/9931-wireless-arduino-uploading-using-esp8266

Comment: @Gerben I don't see any reference to SSH on that page.

Comment: @NickGammon simply that I could create sketches on my computer and upload them with an ssh connection to whatever board is hooked up to the arduino, rather than unplugging either device and walking across the room every time I want to upload

Comment: [SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) is a secure (encrypted) shell. Why do you need to encrypt an upload from one part of your room to the other?

Comment: @NickGammon I don't, it just seemed like the easiest way to link the two terminals, and I have a friend who did it and said it works fine for him.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want an [Arduino Yun](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardYun) instead of an Uno.  Or a [Dragino Yun Shield](http://www.dragino.com/products/yunshield/item/86-yun-shield.html) that turns your Uno into a Yun.

Comment: Yeah I confirm. I did some work recently and the Arduino Yùn Shield could do the job. You can push sketches via Wifi and run ssh commands. I add performance problem, but otherwise it works like a charm.

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoYunShield

Answer (score 0):

If you get it working on the Pi2, could you just drop in a Pi Zero ($5) and a cheap USB network adapter ($2)?

Note that your question title asks for "best", but you don't define your criteria.  Reading between the lines I suspect "cheapest and adequate" is what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You could swap out the Arduino for a ESP012, not sure it meets your I/O needs. The new ESPs support over wifi firmware uploads.